# smpt lib multiple module error with a macbookpro

Tags: python, email, ssl, smtp

My code I have copied and pasted from real python.com

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "sender@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "reciever@gmail.com"
password = input("Type your password and press enter:")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

this somehow simple code to send an email produces a large list of errors which i cant track down.It seems to be an error with the module but im unaware how to resolve or trouble shoot these errors. I cant find any information on it as well; ive been looking for the past hour?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaiwhitehouse/Documents/RetailEmailapp/lhbhbhlbhjbhjlbjljklhkjh.py", line 16, in <module>
    server.starttls(context=context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 774, in starttls
    self.sock = context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
```

Im running on mac os with a 2020 macbook pro but does anyone know the solution to my problem?

Comment: I am unable to repro with the code you posted. I would start looking into problems with your SSL installation rather than a Python problem.

Comment: (The roundabout `context` dance looks like something you had to use back in much earlier versions of Python; `smtplib` can handle `startls` without an argument just fine these days.)